# Typescript: Generic prop doesn't infer the type correctly

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-generics

I have a following code:

```
interface Data {
  [x: string]: number;
}

type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? U
  : T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U
    ? U
    : T extends Promise<infer U>
      ? U
      : T;

interface Props<T extends Data[]> {
  data: T
  xLabel: Extract<keyof Unpacked<T>, string>;
  yLabel: Extract<keyof Unpacked<T>, string>;
}

const Chart = <T extends Data[]>({ data, xLabel, yLabel }: Props<T>): ReactElement => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VictoryChart width={350} theme={VictoryTheme.material}>
        <VictoryArea data={data} x={xLabel} y={yLabel} />
        <VictoryAxis />
      </VictoryChart>
    </View>
  );
};

const data = [
  { quarter: 1, earnings: 13000 },
  { quarter: 2, earnings: 16500 },
  { quarter: 3, earnings: 14250 },
  { quarter: 4, earnings: 19000 },
];

const Home = (): ReactElement => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <ScrollView
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator
    >
      <Block>
        <Chart data={data} xLabel="abc" yLabel="earnings" />
      </Block>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Based on my understandings, xLabel="abc" should result in error because it is not the key of the data ("quarter" or "earnings" only in this case). However, unfortunately, xLabel and yLabel is type of "string", which's not what I expected. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? This seems to produce an error as you expect... see the link in the next comment (it is too long to put it in this one)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.5.1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5AbQA8AuZAZzClAHMBdckAVwFsAjaAblwF9dcYAJ4AHFAFUQIxAGsIAEwA8AFQB8yALzJlyCMUgh5FZAEEoUOEMWgY0ZONX5kAfntOmEAG7cBoSLEQUAAUoAHsRChVdfQhDY3RMQnp1PAJ5DDhyZR4CYgAZOE4AG3IAUX0LBDBFOSFQmHspWQUVVQAaSmo6VRzkIQLisorEatr6xukEOSU1DqoaEFoevgEYZhAq4FCQZABhAAs4KGqdPQMjNAyk1QAKbHTMDvzCiCKO-pei3nIQ8Mi1ACUOH4uAQ2yoyAeWC0hCc2GQAEdmEd-OQAIwdCBHEB0CjogDMAAZicheG04YjkcdoOQAEyY7G49EANgArCSyRSkSiach8QyoDjFnjkGiACy09mk8kEeHc6lQchigVC2gitEATmJhOluHoPFwigOKMhGQ09wyvGQz2KGgA5IUEHa+gNXvasYLcXaAPSqIA

Comment: It's v3.9.7: https://i.imgur.com/I1TErlt.png. As you can see in the attachment, it shows as "string". I think it's not the issue of Typescript, it's VSCode itself